# Grouping in WebGrid in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want result display Grouping records in WebGrid.

Means when repeat data is there based on particular id then it will show in group.

I have try it with Nested Webgrid but not works for me.

I have attached screen shot where i mention how the result will display.!

[image]